# Запятая после "значит"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такого типа: "Эти песни им не интересны, значит(,) играть их не обязательно". Тут нужна запятая после "значит" или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если слово "значит" стоит между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми. Об этом есть информация здесь: http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html

Comment: Мне кажется упоминание бессоюзного сложного предложения здесь избыточно, только путает.  
В значении "стало быть", "следовательно" слово "значит" обособляется всегда.

Comment: Тут другое. Многие между частями БСП перед ЗНАЧИТ тире ставят. Поэтому дробится правило и особо оговариваются БСП и СПП.

Answer (score 0):

Нужна! это вводное слово.